# BroadcastReceiver from Widget to to Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, broadcastreceiver

I got a problem.
I have a widget, a widget has a button(start recording), If I press that button I want my button in main activity being pressed as well.  I've seen some apps have that functionality.
I've been trying different ways having WidgetProvider declared within main MainActivity or Declaring BroadcastReceiver in same way, but I get Java access not allowed exception...

Is that possible to receive a button press on widget within my MainActivity ? Maybe using Service ?

The idea is that it passing data from widget to activity through service. So

**Activity <-> Service <-> Widget**

Answer (score 0):

If you press a button in your widget, it means your Activity is in a paused state. So on the button press, just set a flag in preferences and read the flag when you resume your Activity.

Comment: The idea is to pass data from widget to activity through service. So

Activity <-> Service <-> Widget